# Sort combination of data based on maximum of occurrence

Tags: delphi

I have a combination of data of RGBA values in a memory table I got from Rest Response Adapter like these for each row:

```
"R", "A"
"B"
"A","R"
"R","G"
"B"
...
```

I need to sort these data based on the maximum of occurrence or repeat inside the table. For example values `"R","A" = "A","R`this mean the count of this value is 2 and so on.

I was thinking to use Dictionary but it does not have a method to count values and consider RA = AR. And if I loop for each value it will take very long time so how I should solve this problem ?

Comment: But you can swap a pair of values before adding into dictionary (sort for long sequences).

Comment: @MBo How to swap ? and RGBA is not fixed it can be later RGBO.

Comment: So, count them, and then sort them.

Comment: `How to swap?`  'RA'=>'AR'.  An I feel that you have not described all the important details of ypur problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have something highly specific. In this case you can optimize it using bit operations:

```
type
  TCounts = array[0..15] of Integer;

const 
  RGBA_R = 1;
  RGBA_G = 2;
  RGBA_B = 4;
  RGBA_A = 8;

function GetCounts(const Strings: array of string): TCounts;
var
  i, j, k: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  Fillchar(Result, Sizeof(Result), 0);
  for i := 0 to Length(Strings) - 1 do
  begin
    k := 0;
    s := Strings[i];
    for j := 1 to Length(s) do
      case s[i] of
        'R': k := k or RGBA_R;
        'G': k := k or RGBA_G;
        'B': k := k or RGBA_B;
        'A': k := k or RGBA_A;
        '"', ' ', ',': ; // do nothing
      else
        // handle error here
      end;

    Inc(Result[k]);
  end;
end;
```

The total number of all combinations of `R, G, B` is `Result[RGBA_R or RGBA_G + RGBA_B]`.